# Django rest frameworok

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to make a `django-rest-framework` serializer where a related model can be linked by list instead of by detail

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Log(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='logs')

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    logs = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='log-detail')
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('logs', 'url', 'device_id')
```

If I navigate to 'api/devices' is will return a list of devices like so:

```
[
    {
        "device_id": "12345"
        "url": "http://localhost/api/devices/12345"
        "logs": [
            "http://localhost/api/logs/1",
            "http://localhost/api/logs/2"
            "http://localhost/api/logs/3"
            "http://localhost/api/logs/4"
        ]
    }
]
```

There can be many many logs. I don't want to write custom logic for pagination of logs inside the Device model, that should be handled by a Logs view.

I would like to have a result like this:

```
[
    {
        "device_id": "12345"
        "url": "http://localhost/api/devices/12345"
        "logs": [
            "http://localhost/api/logs?device_id=12345"
        ]
    }
]
```

And a api consumer can just navigate to the provided link to get the device logs.

It seems that serializer relations don't handle this use case. Can someone point me in the most framework idiomatic way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you asking that the logs field in the devices record return something of the sort `api/logs?id=1-4`?

Comment: No I want it to return a fully realised url to where you can retrieve all the logs for a particular device

Comment: Make an endpoint `api/device/:id/logs` that returns all the logs for that device :id.  Just have serializer override the logs field with that url.

Comment: That is something I want to avoid - because you would end up duplicating the logic of the Logs Viewset - things like querying etc would all need to re-created inside the `device/:id/logs logic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one of the solutions:

Create a method (or property) in the Device model called, for example, `get_logs_url`, that returned url for device logs:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    ...
    get_logs_url(self):
        # First parameter is the url name, 'device-logs' for example
        return reverse('device-logs', kwargs={'device_id': self.device_id})
```

Add field `logs_url` to DeviceSerializer

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    logs_url = serializers.CharField(source='get_logs_url', read_only=True)
```

Then the result would be like this

```
[
    {
        "device_id": "12345"
        "logs": "/api/logs?device_id=12345"
    }
]
```

If you want absolute url in result then your serializer should look something like this

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logs_url = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_logs_url(self, device):
        return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(device.get_logs_url())
```

Then the result would be like this

```
[
    {
        "device_id": "12345"
        "logs": "http://localhost/api/logs?device_id=12345"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't think you can get a fully qualified url this way because reverse won't have access to the request object - so logs_url would look like `/api/logs?device_id=12345`? and not `http://localhost/api/logs?device_id=12345`